# Macros for VSCode terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, macros, command

I want to run shortcut commands in the terminal which i need to type frequently

example: "rs" will run "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80"
or       "fr" will run "flutter run"

in the terminal.

Any extensions that already do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell aliases would be the usual way to do what you want.  You do not identify which shell you are using - but you should search for how to do aliases in your shell.

You can also use the `sendSequence` command to send any text to the terminal in a shortcut.  In keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+z",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": { "text": "flutter run\u000d" },
}
```

The `\u000d` is a return so the command runs immediately.